# I configure 2 files for 2 different domains, both pointing to port 80. But the second domain doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs, nginx, config, nginx-config

I use a static IP and configure 2 files for 2 different domains, both pointing to port 80. But the second domain doesn't seem to work.
Config domain1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2MpO.png)

Config domain 2:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CakzP.png)

I tried changing the second domain's port to port 90 and it worked normally. Or put both domains to port 90 and both will run

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshott.